# Logic app completing a message in a service bus topic subscription with sessions does not release the lock

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have an topic subscription on a service bus in Azure with a lock duration of 30 seconds and sessions enabled.

[image]

I'm using a logic app to take messages of the topic using peak-lock because I care about the order messages are processed. I want to ensure that all messages with the same session id are processed in the order they are added to the bus i.e. FIFO.

Below is a screenshot of a simple logic app which is triggered when a message arrives (peek-lock with 5 second polling), it then waits for 15 seconds before completing the message.

[image]

When I load 10 messages on to the topic, the first instance of the logic app is triggered as you would expect and completes in roughly 15 seconds, however the second logic app doesn't start for another 15 seconds i.e. 30 seconds in total after the first logic app started (the length of the lock duration).

[image]

Everything I have read suggests that completing a message should release the lock immediately but this doesn't appear to be the case. Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it is meant to work?

Answer (score 1):

> Everything I have read suggests that completing a message should
>   release the lock immediately but this doesn't appear to be the case.
>   Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it is meant to work?

LockDuration instructs a queue (subscription is a queue after all) to keep messages invisible from competing consumers to ensure the current processing node can handle it within the time frame defined by LockDuration. Renew lock mechanism ensures that the lock on the currently being processed message is extended to allow longer than LockDuration processing time if needed so. An important thing to remember, lock renewal is not guaranteed to be successful.

**Scenario 1**:

However, I have tried replicating your workflow with a small change in Topic Subscription Lock Duration as 2 minutes (to see if LockDuration property influences the LA trigger) and provided the SessionID manually. Below is my test result.

I have loaded the first 10 messages into the topic.
[image]

From the above images, you could see the second instance of the Logic App Trigger initiated right after completing the first instance.

**Scenario 2:**
In this case, I have maintained the same configuration but changed the SessionId to "**NextAvailable**". Now, The Logic App trigger awaits the entire lock duration (2 min and even more sometimes) and triggers the next instance.

[image]

In conclusion, if you having the same session Id for your messages and configuring the Session ID as "Next available" in your LA UI, then it locks the message for the entire LockDuration time frame. If you want to avoid this, then you need to "Close a session in a queue" at the client-side. This will immediately release the lock and process the next instance immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The combination to use in order to achieve your desired outcome is as follows, assuming you are using a topic and not a queue, although it possible to achieve same with queue, just use the equivalent queue activities:

1. Use `When a message is received in a topic subscription (peek-lock)` trigger to pull message from subscription, use **'Next available'** as the Session Id
2. Initialise a variable e.g. `WorkflowStatus` and set to nothing, this will signal the next step to break out of loop
3. Following step 2, create a parallel branch, Use Logic App Activity  `Renew lock on the session in a topic subscription` inside an `Until` Logic App Activity together with a `Delay` activity
4. Use the following to break out Until loop: `length(variables('WorkflowStatus'))` is greater than 0
5. Ensure the delay is at least 5 seconds less than your topic's max lock duration
6. Create a `try`, `catch`, `finally` scope in your main branch
7. When your Logic App workflow completes, first, signal the `Until` activity to stop renewing your lock
8. Signal by setting `WorkflowStatus` variable to Success inside the end of `try` scope and Failure inside the beginning of `catch` scope
9. Use `Complete the message in a topic subscription` activity in the `finally` scope if `WorkflowStatus` is success
10. Use `Close a session in the topic` activity in the `finally` scope if `WorkflowStatus` is success
11. Use `Dead-letter the message in a topic subscription` activity in the `finally` scope if `WorkflowStatus` is failure
12. Best practice to terminate the Logic App workflow as either succeeded or failed based on value of `WorkflowStatus`
13. Best practice to offer up the `Dead-letter the message in a topic subscription`  reason for dead-lettering as the Workflow Error Message extracted from `catch` scope

**Here is an example:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Improvements:**

1. You could include another `Until` activity in the `try` block to
   wait for more messages to arrive in the locked session for a
   configurable duration and fetch messages by session Id that the
   trigger provided you.
2. Abandon the message if the work in the `try` scope fails for a reason that warrants another go e.g. a remote endpoint is unreachable even after retry exhaustion

**This example uses the following tools:**

- Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030
- Function Runtime Version:   4.15.2.201
- Azure Logic Apps (Standard) v1.0.46 Visual Studio Code Extension
- Azurite v3.22.0 Visual Studio Code Extension

For more information on how to extract the error message in the catch scope see Approach 1 at the following link

[Logic App Exception Handling With The Result Function](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/logic-app-best-practices-tips-and-tricks-15-logic-app-failure-notification)

For more information on how to use an `Until` activity to fetch more messages from the topic for a configurable amount of time, see the sequential convoy pattern at the following link

[While there are more messages for the session in the queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/send-related-messages-sequential-convoy)

You only really need to do this if you anticipate 'large volumes' of messages per Session Id.

Answer (score -1):

When you close the session, it assumes there are no more messages on it and then you lose them all.
How do I avoid losing messages and still processing them asap and not wait for the lock duration to finish?
I have a Sessionful receiver, next available, I complete the message as soon as I receive it and then I close the session. Meanwhile, a new message on that session arrived, and because I Closed the session, that message is lost.

[image: this is microsoft documentation picture]

Comment: The better idea is to put the URL of the page instead of the screenshot

Comment: I am using the Logic App Activity 'Close a session in the topic' and passing in the Session Id I took from the trigger that uses 'Next available' Session Id. It does not remove all the messages from the queue with the same Session Id.